# What are the valid parameters date offset strings in pandas?

Tags: pandas

Various `pandas` functions allow for an argument to specify frequencies, e.g. `freq` in

```
pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
```

[(source)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)

and the first argument in

```
series.resample('3T', how='sum', label='right')
```

[(source)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)

I can figure out empirically what `H` and `3T` mean, but if I want to create my own frequencies I'm stuck. What are these parameters, and how can I find out how to form my own?

Answer (score 3):

The valid frequency codes can be found in the documentation under [Offset Aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).  The next sections, [Combining Aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#combining-aliases) and [Anchored Offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets), are also relevant.

Essentially, any number that you see preceding an offset alias is just a multiplier for the offset alias.  For example, `T` means minutely, so `3T` means every 3 minutes.

```
pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3, freq='T')
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:01:00', '2015-01-01 00:02:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='T')

pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3, freq='3T')
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:03:00', '2015-01-01 00:06:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3T')
```

You can also combine offset aliases.  For example, `2H3T` would be a frequency of every 2 hours and 3 minutes.  The order in which offset aliases are combined does not matter; `2H3T` is equivalent to `3T2H`.  Note that there are some offset aliases that currently do not combine, e.g. `MS` and `T`.

Anchored offsets allow you modify when some of the potentially ambiguous offset alias start/stop.  For example, the weekly offset `W` implicitly has the week start on Sunday.  If you want the week to start on Thursday, you would use the Thursday anchor: `W-THU`.